# Pair two pandas dataframes via a series who have almost same values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time

I have a dataframe df1 with time series as follows:

```
1     2020-06-07T19:42:32.000-0700
3     2020-06-05T22:41:25.000-0700
6     2020-06-09T10:46:07.000-0700
7     2020-06-07T16:36:05.000-0700
8     2020-06-06T16:44:06.000-0700
11    2020-06-06T21:19:12.000-0700
12    2020-06-06T15:28:10.000-0700
13    2020-06-06T11:09:36.000-0700
15    2020-06-07T11:49:17.000-0700
21    2020-06-07T15:17:23.000-0700
23    2020-06-07T21:12:30.000-0700
28    2020-06-06T20:00:12.000-0700
Name: _time, dtype: object
```

and a dataframe df2 with time series as follows:

```
0     2020-06-07T16:36:05.000-0700
1     2020-06-07T15:17:23.000-0700
9     2020-06-06T20:00:12.000-0700
12    2020-06-09T10:46:07.000-0700
14    2020-06-06T15:28:10.000-0700
15    2020-06-06T11:09:36.000-0700
16    2020-06-07T11:49:17.000-0700
20    2020-06-07T19:42:32.000-0700
21    2020-06-06T21:19:12.000-0700
22    2020-06-06T16:44:05.000-0700
25    2020-06-07T21:12:30.000-0700
26    2020-06-05T22:41:25.000-0700
Name: _time, dtype: object
```

Although these timestamps are not exactly similar, I would like to pair off the rows from each dataframe with the closest number.

Comment: `merge_asof` them with a theshold, docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html

Comment: Thanks, how do we sort the keys if they are in datetime format? A simple `df.sort_values(by = ['_time'])` does not sort them.

Comment: it sorts the same way as your comment(if the dtype is a datetime) , you might have to assign them back , `df = df.sort_values(..)`